# Add custom js file to JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to include a javascript file which is not available as bower.

So I copied it to **src/main/webapp/content** and referenced in index.html

In the **DEV** profile all is fine -- it works.

Now, after generating WAR file with the **PROD** profile, the custom.js file is not included in the WAR (tried to unpack -- file is not there).

I have discovered the gulp is merging all css and js files, did I miss a config for this?

When the app is loaded, the browser complains with 404 in the index.html -- js file not found.

How can I fix this? What is the right way to include JS (or CSS) file into JHipster app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS are not expected to be in `content` folder.

For CSS, copy your file to `src/main/webapp/content/css`.

For JS, copy your file to `src/main/webapp/app` possibly in a dedicated sub folder.

You don't have to inject them in `index.html`, gulp will do it for you. I suppose you did not see it in `dev` profile because you were not running `gulp serve` [as explained in the doc](https://jhipster.github.io/development/#using-the-java-server-and-gulp-together)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Initially I have created src/main/webapp/content/script folder, in DEV it was picking it up, but in PROD -- the folder was missing, so I tried to put in to content --  same. I will try with app folder!

Comment: yes, I missed the gulp serve :( I see the injected line in the index.html, thank you!